# is it a bad practice modifing an object passed as an argument inside a method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

is it a bad practice modifing an object passed as an argument inside a method?

what is the difference between doSomething1 and doSomething2? the both does the same but in a different way. which are appropriate and why is that?

```
class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.bar = { aaa: 123, bbb: 456 }
    this.doSomething1(this.bar)
    this.doSomething2()
  }

  doSomething1(arg) { arg.aaa = 10 },
  doSomething2() { 
    this.bar.bbb = 0
  }

}
```

the code itself is not practical but just a sample code.

Comment: Not really the correct site to post this, but the answer is, depends.

Comment: did I post this in a wrong SO community? Im using a mobile app of SO and not sure where my question is posted...

Comment: Yes, you've used StackOverflow, it's really meant to help with finding bugs with code, and not advice on coding practices.  CodeReview is more for this type of question -> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Keith This doesn't seem appropriate for CodeReview. That's for real code with a specific goal. [softwareengineering.se] takes questions about general design principles, although this seems to minor for them as well.

Comment: @Barmar  Crikey, how many sub-sites does this company have.. :),..

Comment: @Keith Lots, yet it's quite possible that this isn't really a good fit for any of them. :)

Answer (score 1):

That's the difference between a function and a method. A method, which is a function defined on an object, knows all the properties of the object and is allowed to modified them (also known as mutate or change the state). `doSomething2` is a method of `Foo` class. Hence it should have the right or privilege to mutate any of the properties of an instance of `Foo`.

`doSomething1` on the other hand is a function masquerading as a method. It has no right to modify the argument it receives and so shouldn't. If it really must, then create a new copy with the updated property instead.

Comment: Yes. That's what I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `doSomething1` can be used to modify *any* object, while `doSomething2()` is specifically designed to modify only the `bar` property of the object `Foo` object that it's called on.

So `doSomething1()` is a more general function. Since it doesn't reference `this`, it doesn't really even need to be in the class, except that the class limits how you can call it.

Also, to call class methods you need to call it on an object, `this.methodname(...)`.

```
var abc = {};

class Foo {
  constructor () {
    this.bar = { aaa: 123, bbb: 456 }
    this.doSomething1(this.bar)
    this.doSomething2()
    this.doSomething1(abc)
  }

  doSomething1(arg) { arg.aaa = 10 },
  doSomething2() { 
    this.bar.bbb = 0
  }
}
```

Comment: I think doSomething1 should return a new object.

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: @shu Also  `doSomething2()` won't work, as it should be -. `this.doSomething2()`

Answer (score 0):

Modern JavaScript is taking a lot of notes from the functional programming world these days. In functional programming you never modify anything. The question you are asking is highly subjective and many people will have different opinions but my opinion is that this will fail a tech test for you instantly. If I saw you do that in a tech interview that would be the instant I made my mind up and you would definitely not get the position based solely on seeing you modify a function parameter no matter how good the rest of the interview went.

Return a new instance of an object.

```
return { ...arg, prop: 'New value' };
```

Comment: I agree. I never modify an object passed as an argument. but, why is this bad practice?

Comment: Because you never know where else that object is being used. If you create a new instance of the object for the code you are writing the function for you can be 100% certain that you haven't affected another part of the app you were not anticipating. I suggest reading up on functional programming and data immutability.

Comment: @shu  It's not!!, like everything in any programming language, use the right tools for the job.

Comment: I honestly would have agreed with that statement a year or two ago, but after learning how much more productive and how many fewer defects you get I haven't looked back.

Comment: but what is the difference between the two methods? both mutate an object.

Comment: @AdrianBrand  I understand the benefits, especially in an async language like Javascript, but sometimes mutating state is exactly what your after, and cloning / copying would only be getting in the way.  It's the reason, why my first response was `it depends`.

Comment: You never mutate an object, you create a new instance with the changes required. Look into what the spread operator does.